# How to draw an image of any layout level in HTML5

Tags: html, actionscript-3, canvas

In as3 there is addChild() with one parametr of about layout. You may insert any image to any layout. Is there an option in HTML5 too?

I see method draw() for context in HTML5. But it was inserts into the last layout.

Comment: There is no sibling idea in canvas 2d context API. Only pixels. You can control if these pixels are drawn on top or behind existing content, but that's about (if we forget about more complex compositing ops). If you want a way to handle layers, you'll have to build it yourself. It's actually quite simple : create multiple canvases, and draw them in the desired order on a main one. `ctx.drawImage` does accept an canvas as source.

Comment: @Kaiido, Can you show an example, thanks.